# getting Error: logical(1)): anyNA() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language' Traceback when using prediction function

Tags: r, prediction, linear-programming

trying to compute AUC model using ROCR package

```
set.seed(144)

split = sample.split(loans_data, SplitRatio=0.7) 

test_data  = subset(loans_data, split==FALSE)

predict_train = glm(not.fully.paid ~ credit.policy+purpose+int.rate+installment+log.annual.inc+dti+fico+days.with.cr.line+revol.bal+revol.util+inq.last.6mths+delinq.2yrs+pub.rec, data=train_data, family=binomial)


ROCR_predictions = prediction(predict_train, test_data$not.fully.paid)
```

getting this when running the above

```
Error in vapply(predictions, anyNA, logical(1)): anyNA() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
Traceback:

1. prediction(predict_train, test_data)
2. vapply(predictions, anyNA, logical(1))
```

I want to be able to plot that predictions

Comment: It would be helpful for you to add data to your question by pasting the output of `dput(loans_data)` or if it is a large data set `dput(head(loans_data))`. If you cannot share your data then please create some fake data that reproduces your issue.